# Django use base.html but table can't show

Tags: django, templates

> wanip.html

[image]

> base.html

[image]

use `base.html` in `wanip.html` ,can't show table .how can I use `base.html` right?

Comment: Don't post images of code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

You should create block in `base.html` and override that block in `wanip.html`.
Just for your reference.

base.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    ....
    </head>
    <body>
    ....
    {% block content %}
    ....
    {% endblock content %}
    ....
    </body>
    </html>
```

And wanip.html will be like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{block.super}}
<table>...</table>
{% endblock content %}
```